# Is it legal to keep a package that was accidentally addressed to you?

Tags: criminal-law, theft, mail, postal-service

When I try to research this question, all the scenarios people suggest are significantly different to my own. This is not one of those cases where a company tries to run a scam by sending someone goods in the hopes of billing them at a later date. It's also not a situation where I have received a package that was not addressed to me.

Here is what happened.

We received a package here in New York. The package had two shipping labels on it. Both labels have the same return address, a warehouse in North Carolina.
One of the shipping labels was addressed to our home, and the carrier was UPS.
The other shipping label was addressed to a retail store in Canada. The carrier for that label is unknown. Inside the box is semi-luxury merchandise that I would estimate has a retail value about $2000-3000 US.

What happened is pretty obvious. The package was intended to be shipped from the warehouse to the retail store. Someone at the warehouse slapped a UPS label addressed to us on the box by accident. A UPS courier picked up the package, ignoring the other shipping label, and it ended up at our home.

For the record, I am making efforts to contact the warehouse, the store, and UPS to return the package. I believe that is what will end up happening.

The question is, what if I didn't? If I decided to just keep or sell this merchandise, would that be a crime of some sort? You could say that their mistake is our good fortune, but the presence of the second shipping label makes the situation quite ambiguous.

Comment: I am fairly sure this was asked and answered before...

Comment: @Trish I found lots of similar questions, but all of the other scenarios were meaningfully different from this one.

Comment: @Trish I think that the existence of two shipping labels, and the fact that it is a private delivery service (UPS) v. mail, may distinguish it.

Comment: How curious.  Are the two shipping labels completely separate and intact, like not even overlapping, nor with any indications that they attempted to peel off, cross out, or cover up one of them? Ultimately I'm not sure what the answer here is either way, but I imagine if there are reasonably clear indicators that one label was intended to be disregarded in favor of the other then that'd likely be relevant.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Yes, they are two completely separate shipping labels, uncovered. The one for our home was actually much less clear than the other one, it was just on top, and the other was on the side. I think the other one was for a non-UPS carrier. I think that since a UPS courier picked up the package, they followed that label, and ignored the other one.